# Add A Loading Image to Website

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am making a website by using Wordpress. In the customizer,I've added "loader" style and js code. Also I add a  tag in the _header.php file. But the web page always staying in the loading image.What’s the problem?

CSS:

```
#loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/36zxp64.jpg?1') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
</script>
```

Comment: First, ask yourself "do I really need a loader?" If your site's slow enough to want one, fix that instead. Especially if you're using that giant, nearly 1MB image as a loader...

Comment: Forget an image, use CSS3. http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/hzDqw

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. If you really have those curly quotes (“ ”) they'll throw an error (you need to use straight quotes (" ") instead).

Comment: @ceejayoz,My supervisor wants the loading page...and I said website may take more time to load the loading image than the site..but she still wants it...

Comment: @RCorrie,I know you're right.But my supervisor wants that huge image..I have no choice...I've changed the quotes to straight,but it still always stay on the loading image.

Comment: In that case, I would extract that background and make it smaller, then recreate the rest of the elements in html/css. Your supervisor is making a horrible decision.

Comment: @RCorrie,I've compressed that image.I think the reason of always staying in the loading image is that the website doesn't load the jquery library.Is any thing wrong with my js code?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the 'load' event, use the 'Document ready' event. I edited a new working jsfiddle. You can specify a longer or quicker fade effect by changing the value, in milliseconds.

```
//Jquery on page Ready event
$(function(){
   $("#loader").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf5n6/2/)

"The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code." [Taken from Jquery Document Ready page] (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It works locally and in your jsfiddle.But it doesn't work in my website...It seems the site doesn't load the jquery,so the page always stay on the loading image...I don't know why...

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser Web Dev console? Is jquery loaded? Maybe another script file comes into conflict with jquery.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you load jquery BEFORE your custom script, otherwise nothing will be executed. just saying

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("#loader").fadeOut(1000);
});
</script>`

Comment: I think I load the jquery before the custom script.The website is based on the Wordpress and I bought a theme, maybe the js code conflict with some scripts in the theme.Thanks for your reply..

Comment: The problem is solved....In the wordpress's custom part,I don't need to add <script> tag.So when I delete the tag,it works! Thanks!